# Execute condition in if statement in the particular order

Tags: python, if-statement, recursion

I am working on a Python project solving maze with a recursive approach. The user can choose the directions 'NESW' of each cell to be checked in the order they want. To make things simpler, I written the following code to illustrate my question.

```
def check(x, y, user_order):
<snip>
    *assuming user_order is 'NESW'*
    if check(x, y + 1) or check(x + 1, y) or check(x, y - 1) or check(x - 1, y):
        return True
<snip>
```

The if statement is going to return True anyway if there is a path. However, the 'check' function marks and unmarks cells of the maze during the recursive calls and order matters. How should I implement the order to the conditions in the if statement?

Answer (score 1):

> How should I implement the order to the conditions in the if statement?

This will take much more than just changing your if statement. First you will need to pass `order` in as a parameter rather than using a hardcodeed value. Then you will need to loop over the characters in `order` and check the direction each one specifies.

If you are still stuck trying to figure this out, I suggest you step back from the code and describe in words what steps you need to solve the problem.